# Flutter add animation small to big

Tags: flutter

Need to know how can i add some animation on my splash screen. I just need to add when app open the center image will show small to large.

My code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
            () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen())));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/bg@3x.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset("assets/logo@2x.png"),
        ) /* add child content here */,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tween` `AnimationController` with `AnimatedBuilder` to for this purpose. Here's an example you just need to replace `Container` with your `Image` or you can also wrap the Image with a Container.

Since, you want the `image` to increase the size at splash screen so use `forward()` property of `AnimationController` in `initState`.

Then replace the `height` and `width` property of your image with `_animationSize.value`. Adjust the size according to your need here:

**Size:**

```
_tweenSize = Tween(begin: 50, end: 200);
```

**Duration:**

```
_animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400));
```

**Replace:**

```
 AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationSize,
            builder: (context, child) {
              // Put your image here and replace height, width of image with _animationSize.value
              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: _animationSize.value,
                width: _animationSize.value,
              );
            }),
```

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Tween<double> _tweenSize;
  Animation<double> _animationSize;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400));
    _tweenSize = Tween(begin: 50, end: 200);
    _animationSize = _tweenSize.animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationSize,
            builder: (context, child) {
              // Put your image here and replace height, width of image with _animationSize.value
              return Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: _animationSize.value,
                width: _animationSize.value,
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```